# Mongoose not retrieving the same data as mongo console client

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So, I have a Mongo database with a collection where the documents have a structure similar to this:

```
{
  "name": "sampleName",
  "subdocument": [
      {
        "name": "subDocName",
        "subsubdocument": [...]
      }
  ]
}
```

When running mongoose it returns the subsubdocument array empty for all the documents even if they have data. If I run a mongo client on a console I can retrieve the information with no problem at all.

But it gets weirder: if I run the following on my nodejs endpoint it returns an empty array, suggesting there are no empty subsubdocument arrays in any of my documents (which I can confirm from a direct access to the database is true).

```
MyCollection.find({'subdocument.subsubdocument': {$eq: []}},function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Although if I run the code bellow all my subsubdocument arrays are printed as [ ].

```
MyCollection.find(function(err, result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I have even used a GUI (mongobooster) to check if I was not going crazy.

I have no clue of what is going on here and no idea how to solve this so please any ideas are welcome.

PS: I am using version 3.2 of MongoDB and mongoose v4.4.12.

Comment: Your Mongoose models you have created are incorrect, or it doesn't match whatever you have stored in your mongo database.

Comment: Ok, I'll check it.But is that the default behavior? Shouldn't it return an error instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears it was a rather stupid error that I wasn't thinking of because I assumed the standard behavior would be different. It was just a confusion with some git versions that caused an error on the mongoose schema.

I just thought if it was that it should show an error and not just hide the information, rather strange indeed...

But thanks to Inder R Singh to pointing me out in the right direction.